# Does the AWS Admin user have the eks:AccessKubernetesApi permission?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iam, eks

I am logged in to AWS as the AWS Admin, with Administrator access.

How do I find out if this user has the `eks:AccessKubernetesApi` IAM permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to perform the action you're looking for.  I'll demonstrate how to accomplish this task from the command line and the console.  Using the SDK's (e.g. boto3) are an option too.

From the command line you can use:

```
aws iam simulate-principal-policy --policy-source-arn <arn of role or user> --action-names eks:AccessKubernetesApi --query 'EvaluationResults[].EvalDecision'
```

It will return the following if you have access :

> [ "allowed" ]

From the console use the [IAM Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/)
Pick the Role/User/Group that you wish to test:

[image]

Then choose the service:

[image]

And the action(s):

[image]

Click `Run Simulation` and the results will be published:

[image]

**References**
[Simulate Principle Policy](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/iam/simulate-principal-policy.html)
[Access Policies Testing Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html)